# jQuery AJAX request fails with 503 error only with "http://example.com" as value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, http-status-code-503

I have the strangest problem. This is my javascript:

```
var value = "some_value";
$.ajax({
  url: "process.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    value: value
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

No surprises here. This is my process.php:

```
<?php exit; ?>
```

Actually it does not matter, what is inside the `process.php`.
The request is successful everytime, except when value is a valid URL. With

```
var value = "http://example.com"
```

at the beginning the request will fail with error 503 Service temporarily unavailable.
What is wrong with my server configuration? I don't know what to try.
I have no .htaccess. Browser: Firefox 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a [web application firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall). Check whether your server is running [`mod_security`](https://www.modsecurity.org/).  You will need to review the rules used by `mod_security` or whatever else is running on the server to find the one that is blocking URLs.

Comment: I did not change a thing, and surprisingly today it works... ??? Maybe the server was literally "temporarily unavailable"?

Comment: My hoster (strato.de), by default, runs a check to prevent spam in guestbooks. If a script is accessed too often, it throws a 503. It took a long time until I found the option to deactivate it...

Comment: Glad you figured it out!