# AJAX FormData Post - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I've searched extensively on this problem without avail or maybe I'm missing the issue. Please, relay to me anything I could do to improve on the explanation.

I have a 'File' input that calls for a **Php** file using **Ajax** on **'change'** like so:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="photo"]', function(){

        var file = this.files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        var user = localStorage.getItem("user");

        formData.append('_file', file);
        formData.append('_user', user);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: ip + "php/insert_img.php",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function (e) {
                // do something
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });

    });
```

This is supposed to be a phonegap app, and I'm using Chrome's Ripple Emulator with the Apache Cordova/PhoneGap platform enabled for testing.

Now, everything works as it's supposed to when using localhost, and the PHP prints the formData as it should, however, when I use the same PHP file uploaded to the server (hence the 'ip' variable on Ajax's **url** option), thats a different story.

After sometime it returns the **error** setting and when checking Chrome's developer tools > Network tab, I can see that the 'Status Code' of the request is: 503 Service Unavailable.
BUT, if I change the **data** setting to anything other than a FormData(), it works.

Seems like the issue comes from server settings, but I am not aware of what the problem could be.

Comment: My first thought is to double check the url.  As you mentioned `ip` is defined, but maybe just write it out to the console to make sure.  Add `console.log(ip + "php/insert_img.php");` to the change function and see what comes up.

Comment: a `503` in indicative of a server receiving the request and having issue processing it. Check server logs too, see the nature of the issue. If you have access to the server code-base, log-out the request's specifics (headers, payload, request type, etc ...).

Comment: the ip is good to go, as I mentioned before, if I change the type of data, say data: {someting: value} and use it, it works. Seems like something to to with the FormData Constructor I use.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem many of times when using AJAX so here are my initial thoughts:

Is "ip" defined? **url: ip + "php/insert_img.php"**

Also I found removing some of the extra AJAX options fixed the issue. Amended code below:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="photo"]', function(){

    var file = this.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    var user = localStorage.getItem("user");

    formData.append('_file', file);
    formData.append('_user', user);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ip + "php/insert_img.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function (e) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

**---------- EDIT ----------**

After a bit of searching around, I believe the issue is where you're appending the `_file` and `_user` data. If the values of this data is an array you will have to "stringify" it:

```
formData.append('_file', JSON.stringify(file));
formData.append('_user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes the 'ip' is defined as it outputs correctly in the logs. the contentType and processData is necessary to the type of data, I did remove the cache option to no avail.

Comment: This is almost certainly a [web application firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall). Check whether your server is running [`mod_security`](https://www.modsecurity.org/).  You will need to review the rules used by `mod_security` or whatever else is running on the server to find the one that is blocking URLs. [Found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582490/jquery-ajax-request-fails-with-503-error-only-with-http-example-com-as-value)

Comment: the error is the same, but it works successfully if I do not use the FormData constructor 'new FormData();' and use other type of basic variable.

Comment: @Estobia I have added some extra info to my answer that will hopefully help.

Comment: thanks, they're not an array, but tried it anyhow, but no dice. I managed to change the server of the php files and that solved part of the issue, so probably something to do with that. unfortunately, now I have an empty array on $_FILES from php, although chrome's 'request payload' outputs everything correct. but that would be another question I guess.